# Facebook: How can I get the next/previous image from the profile feed?

Tags: facebook, graph

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed provides only the first image from the number of images posted, in a users wall. how can i get all the rest images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do would be to load the albums of a user (https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums), search for the album with `"name": "Wall Photos"`, take the **id**, call https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUMID and read out the photos this album contains with the [photo connection](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/).